# Are there any significant industrial processes that use liquid ammonia as a solvent?

Tags: synthesis, solvents, applied-chemistry

There are some interesting laboratory reactions that use liquid ammonia as a solvent (for example, the [Birch Reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_reduction) where an alkali metal is dissolved in liquid ammonia).

There have also been some high volume industrial processes that use liquid ammonia as a solvent (the weedkiller paraquat has two, quite different, production routes using liquid ammonia producing thousands of tonnes a year). One uses dissolving sodium (like the Birch reduction):

[image: wikipedia description of one paraquat synthesis]

But are there any other significant chemical manufacturing processes that use it?

NB I would include the production of pharmaceuticals or their ingredients as well as any bulk chemicals.

Answer (score 1):

I might be terribly wrong, but I'm  not aware of any other industrial process involving ammonia as a reactant (fertilizers, caprolactam, amino acids) where liquid ammonia is used as a solvent.

As a side note, liquefication at least plays a role over here (Germany) for the transport in [rail tank cars](http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=dsc_9733s8udq.jpg).